# Java Annotations not working

Tags: java, annotations

I'm trying to use Java annotations, but can't seem to get my code to recognize that one exists. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
  import java.lang.reflect.*;
  import java.lang.annotation.*;

  @interface MyAnnotation{}


  public class FooTest
  { 
    @MyAnnotation
    public void doFoo()
    {       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {               
        Method method = FooTest.class.getMethod( "doFoo" );

        Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();
        for( Annotation annotation : method.getAnnotations() )
            System.out.println( "Annotation: " + annotation  );

    }
  }
```

Comment: you might want to edit the code to remove the unused 'annotations' local variable or use: for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to specify the annotation as being a Runtime annotation using the @Retention annotation on the annotation interface.

i.e.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyAnnotation{}
```

Answer (score 26):

Short answer: you need to add @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) to your annotation definition.

Explanation:

Annotations are by default **not** kept by the compiler.  They simply don't exist at runtime.  This may sound silly at first, but there are lots of annotations that are only used by the compiler (@Override) or various source code analyzers (@Documentation, etc).

If you want to actually USE the annotation via reflection like in your example, you'll need to let Java know that you want it to make a note of that annotation in the class file itself.  That note looks like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation{}
```

For more information, check out the official docs[1](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) and especially note the bit about RetentionPolicy.

Answer (score 3):

Use `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`
Check the below code. It is working for me:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyAnnotation1{}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyAnnotation2{}

public class FooTest {
    @MyAnnotation1
    public void doFoo() {
    }

    @MyAnnotation2
    public void doFooo() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method method = FooTest.class.getMethod( "doFoo" );
        for( Annotation annotation : method.getAnnotations() )
            System.out.println( "Annotation: " + annotation  );

        method = FooTest.class.getMethod( "doFooo" );
        for( Annotation annotation : method.getAnnotations() )
            System.out.println( "Annotation: " + annotation  );
    }
}
```